# d3.js dynamically generated sentence map with curved text

Tags: d3.js

I have the following d3.js [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PRb93/118/) that prints sentences in a wavy line.

As you can see it prints them all overlapping each other. How can I instead achieve the following effect aka fitting them in as best they could going from top to bottom (with some randomness and wavyness)?

[image]

The key is of course in the line:

```
    .append("path").attr("d", "M 10,90 Q 100,15 200,70 Q 340,140 400,30");
```

but how can I generate these strings to do what I want?

**EDIT: Sorry, just fixed wrong js fiddle link!**

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `transform` attribute to move the coordinate system of the elements you append. This way, you can offset each new element by a random amount:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (Math.random() * 50) + "," + (i * (50 + Math.random() * 100)) + ")")
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PRb93/119/). You may have to tweak the numbers to get exactly what you want.